# How do I correctly configure the material icons components to display icons?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Despite carefully following the steps as seen on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI6kQAORiVg I am failing to get `mat-icon` to show in my Angular page. Kindly help me understand where I am going wrong.

Following are the steps I have taken in an attempt to add an icon to my Angular page.

I start by adding the stylesheet link to my angular index.html page

**.../src/index.html**

```
    <head>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="assets/img/logo.png">
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/sax/css/base/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
```

**.../src/app/app.moudule.ts**

The code in the **app.moudule.ts** file looks like the following:

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  MatIconModule,
  MatTabsModule
} from '@angular/material';


@Injectable()
export class Http {}

@NgModule({
    imports:     [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatIconModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: 'xxx',
            libraries: ["places"]
        }),
      MatTabsModule,
      MatToolbarModule
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, MainComponent],
    providers: [RoutingState, AppService {provide: Http, useValue: axios}],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally, the HTML app page that gets generated:

**.../src/app/main/staff/initiation/initiation.component.html**

```
<section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-end" role="toolbar">

  <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example thumbs up SVG icon"></mat-icon>

</section>
```

Comment: I think you pasted the wrong code for the html section :)

Comment: ...also, please check for errors in the console (press F12 in your browser before loading the page).

Comment: @DaggeJ Yes, I had accidentally posted the wrong code. Thank you for notifying me. The post has now been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure `mat-icon` properly, you need to import `MatIconModule` and include the fonts, both of which you have already done. The reason your `mat-icon` is not working correctly is that it isn't being used correctly in your HTML.

To make it work, you need to add the string in between the `mat-icon` tags. To correctly display the `thumb_up` icon, try this.

```html
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example thumbs up SVG icon">thumb_up</mat-icon>
```

Search for the available icons [here](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline) and replace the `thumb_up` text with your desired icons.

Comment: thank you for your response, but sadly your suggested code merely displays the strings between the `mat-con` tags being thumg_up, and not the thumb up icon. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be importing `MatIconModule` correctly and the fonts as well. What is your `@angular/material` version and `@angular` version. Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: @nasg11 My angular/material version is 6.2.1  and  Angular CLI: 6.2.1
Node: 10.16.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.7

Answer (score 1):

The way I know about getting `mat-icon` to work is to use it like this;

```
<mat-icon>alarm</mat-icon>
```

...that is a string identifier between the tags for the image you want. Rest of your setup seems fine.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

Appearently you can register svgIcons in the `MatIconRegistry` service. Your example is apparently based on this approach;

```js
constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        'thumbs-up',
        sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/img/examples/thumbup-icon.svg'));
  }
```

Code above taken from the [angular material icon examples](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/examples). I guess I still prefer to use the string literals as described in my first answer though.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Sadly when I use your suggested code, what displays in the generated page is the word alarm and not the alarm icon.

Comment: OK, is the `initiation.component` in another angular module perhaps where you do not import `MatIconModule`? No errors in the console?

Comment: the error message I see in the console shows: `initiate-transaction:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:5000/assets/sax/css/base/@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.` Could this be the cause? if so, how do I fix this?

Comment: Try to add <base href="/"> in head before linking all css files (https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/170). You might see icons after you get rid of this error. Angular material components tend to not load after exceptions even if not related to that specific component.